# Fuzzy matching to find the index of a word in a sentence Python

Tags: python

I have the following sentence which is Catalan language:

> en aquest sentit, la llei preveu que quan l'administració s'hagi abstingut d'**actuar** per sancionar una determinada conducta, com a conseqüència d'un procés penal, i aquest procediment acabi en sentència absolutòria, podrà iniciar o continuar el corresponent procediment administratiu.

**After tokenizing the sentence and it becomes a list of words**, I need to find the index of the word "**actuar**", but indexof() is not going to work. Moreover, I don't know Catalan language at all, but I have seen cases like "l'" could also be preceding the word I need.

Is there any easy way to fix this?

Comment: What's the problem? Why don't you use the index or find methods? What is your expected output?

Comment: `my_str.index('actuar')` seems to be working as expected.

Comment: I have tokenized the string so that it becomes a list of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
>>> sen = "en aquest sentit, la llei preveu que quan l'administració s'hagi abstingut d'actuar per sancionar una determinada conducta, com a conseqüència d'un procés penal, i aquest procediment acabi en sentència absolutòria, podrà iniciar o continuar el corresponent procediment administratiu."
>>> tokens = sen.split()
>>> tokens
['en', 'aquest', 'sentit,', 'la', 'llei', 'preveu', 'que', 'quan', "l'administraci\xc3\xb3", "s'hagi", 'abstingut', "d'actuar", 'per', 'sancionar', 'una', 'determinada', 'conducta,', 'com', 'a', 'conseq\xc3\xbc\xc3\xa8ncia', "d'un", 'proc\xc3\xa9s', 'penal,', 'i', 'aquest', 'procediment', 'acabi', 'en', 'sent\xc3\xa8ncia', 'absolut\xc3\xb2ria,', 'podr\xc3\xa0', 'iniciar', 'o', 'continuar', 'el', 'corresponent', 'procediment', 'administratiu.']
>>> def get_index(tokens, substr):
...    for i, tk in enumerate(tokens):
...       if substr in tk: return i
... 
>>> get_index(tokens, "actuar")
11
```